# How to annotate only the diagonal elements of a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am using Seaborn heatmap to plot the output of a large confusion matrix. Since the diagonal element represents the correct prediction, they are more important to show the number/correct rate. As the question suggests, how to annotate only the diagonal entries in a heatmap?

I have consulted this website https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html, but it does not help with how to annotate only the diagonal entries. Hope somebody could help with that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help you in getting what you have in mind? The URL example given by you does not have a diagonal, I had annotated the diagonal below the main diagonal instead. To annotate your confusion matrix diagonal, you can adapt to my code by changing the -1 value in `np.diag(..., -1)` to 0.

Note the additional parameter `fmt=''` that I had added in `sns.heatmap(...)` because my `annot` matrix elements are strings.

Code

```
from string import ascii_letters
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="white")

# Generate a large random dataset
rs = np.random.RandomState(33)
y = rs.normal(size=(100, 26))
d = pd.DataFrame(data=y, columns=list(ascii_letters[26:]))

# Compute the correlation matrix
corr = d.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype='bool')
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

# Generate the annotation
annot = np.diag(np.diag(corr.values,-1),-1)
annot = np.round(annot,2)
annot = annot.astype('str')
annot[annot=='0.0']=''

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3, center=0,
            square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}, annot=annot, fmt='')

plt.show()
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Using np.diag is fantastic to solve this issue! Now suppose the values are from 0 to 1, how if I also want to annotate those entries with value larger than 0.1?

Comment: @son520804 If the structure of the matrix allows, you can do logical indexing like I did in my code with the zero values, in particular the line `annot[annot=='0.0']=''`. In your case, it would be `annot[annot>'0.1']=...`. Alternatively, you may create a temporary matrix first with the main diagonal filled but zeros elsewhere, and another temporary matrix with greater than 0.1 entries filled but zeros on the main diagonal and elsewhere, then add them up to be your `annot` matrix. Convert the `annot` matrix to strings and call `annot[annot=='0.0']=''`.

Answer (score 2):

In a related question, someone asked how to annotate the diagonal elements with strings. Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights = flights.pivot('year', 'month', 'passengers')
corr_data = np.corrcoef(flights.to_numpy())

up_triang = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr_data)).astype(bool)
ax = sns.heatmap(corr_data, cmap='flare', xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, square=True,
                 linecolor='white', linewidths=0.5,
                 cbar=True, mask=up_triang, cbar_kws={'shrink': 0.6, 'pad': 0.02, 'label': 'correlation'})
ax.invert_xaxis()
for i, label in enumerate(flights.index):
    ax.text(i + 0.2, i + 0.5, label, ha='right', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with annotated diagonal]