# How to put variable labels on the diagonal of sns heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way how to label a triangular correlation matrix in seaborn/matplotlib as it is done in the R `ggcorr` package (https://briatte.github.io/ggcorr/)? Ie. put the labels on the diagonal "inside" the plot and not on the side as it is done by default in seaborn.

Example:
[image]

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145811/put-variable-names-on-diagonal-of-seaborn-pairgrid) doesn't answer this problem although it is somewhat similar.

EDIT: there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961290/how-to-annotate-only-the-diagonal-elements-of-a-seaborn-heatmap/) which has been mentioned in the comments which by itself asks a different thing and has a different approach and answer but there was recently as a reaction to this quesiton added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961290/how-to-annotate-only-the-diagonal-elements-of-a-seaborn-heatmap/69243722#69243722) which does answer this question.

EDIT2:
Although I do not have any specific data, one can use the ones from the `ggcorr` source for which a simple python code would produce the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv')

# calculate corr
corr = df.corr()
# create masking of the upper triangle
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr), k=0).astype(bool)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

g = sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, 
                square=True, xticklabels=False, linewidths=0.5, cmap="vlag",
               vmin=-1, vmax=1,
               cbar_kws={'shrink': 0.6, 'label': 'correlation', 'aspect':15}
               )

# flip the plot
g.invert_xaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: In the case of this duplicate, it uses the corr values as the annotations, you will have to substitute and build the annotation array with your strings. If you look at the annot array you will see there's a spot for each square. That's how you can annotate the heat map.

Comment: I update the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69243722/12046409) with some code to annotate the diagonal with labels.

Comment: I didn't find the other post, thanks. But maybe it would worth also adding the answer which @JohanC just posted on the other one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69243722/12281892)

Comment: And although I'm not 100% sure but I believe that that answer should be here and not there with a link from there to here because it is answering this question and not exactly the other. It is actually written in the answer that it is answering something different which in my opinion is confusing.

Also, when I'm thinking about it, I don't think it's a duplicate since even though it looks similar, the solution and the problem are different. So should I reopen so that the answer can be added, @JohanC?

Comment: Well, your post doesn't contain test data nor the preliminary code you tried.  As such, it will probably get closed by moderators for not being up to stackoverflow guidelines (See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Adding some random data is very simple, I could use yours. It was a general question, not a code specific, therefore I only added a picture of how I would it to look like in general, but it's not a problem to add some like you did